# How to use msg.data payload with delegatecall to run functions on other contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I'm aware that you can craft function signatures/calls similar to the following:
`address nameReg = 0x72ba7d8e73fe8eb666ea66babc8116a41bfb10e2;
nameReg.call(bytes4(keccak256("fun(uint256)")), a);`

I'm wondering how I would be able to pack together the data when making a delegatecall such I can arbitrarily pass in encoded function signatures.

Comment: Could you please clarify why calling the function of the smart contract directly is no opportunity? I mean the following: `callContract a = callContract("Adress of other contract to be called")` and then call function `a` with `callContract.a(params)`.

Comment: Because calling a function in that manner doesn't have the same effect that `delegatecall` does.